# Printing Address of Struct Element

Tags: pointers, struct, memory-address

I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct Author
{
    char** novels;
} Author;
```

And I want to print the address of an element in the novels array. I tried these two:

```
 printf("%p\n", &(herbert->novels[1]));
 printf("%p\n", herbert->novels[1]);
```

But I'm not sure which is correct. Can someone help me understand which to use and why?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the below...

```
typedef struct Author
{
    char** novels;
} Author;


int main()
{
    Author a;
    char b = 'b';
    a.novels = new char*[2];
    a.novels[0] = NULL;
    a.novels[1] = NULL;

    printf("1. %p\n", a.novels[1]);    
    printf("2. %p\n", &(a.novels[1]));

    delete[] a.novels;
    return 0;
}
```

this outputs the following

```
1. 0000000000000000
2. 00000000001269C8
```

You can see the first print is actually a `NULL` - which is the value stored at the `a.novels[1]`.

The second is the address of the `a.novels[1]` memory.

Assuming you look for the memory address of the item, you'll need the second syntax

`printf("%p\n", &(herbert->novels[1]));`